# apache virtual host config

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

hi im trying to ensure that my website is only accessed via https, and only through the www sub domain, im currently using the following apache virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com

# Redirect http requests to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]

#..
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com

# Redirect http requests to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !=www.example.com
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]

<Directory /home/{apacheuser}/www>
  SSLRequireSSL
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  LimitRequestBody 512000
</Directory>

#..
</VirtualHost>
```

im afraid my knowledge of regex's is rather limited and i am wondering if this is the best way to achieve this?

thankyou

Comment: Is this working or not ?

Comment: no, accessing the website via the ip does not get redirected

Answer (score 0):

1. Just replace

   ```
   # Redirect http requests to https
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
   RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]
   ```

By

```
    # Redirect http requests to https
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
    RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Like that all http trafic will be redirect to https exept http://example.com requests

2. Then remove thoose line from your https configuration :

   ```
   # Redirect http requests to https
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
   RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   ```

so just keep

```
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !=www.example.com
    RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```

which redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com

Answer (score -1):

`%{SERVER_ADDR}` might do the trick to rewrite IP as well

*edit:*

Sorry, you can't use variables on the right side of the expression.

Try something like that:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME},%{SERVER_ADDR} ^(.*),\1
```

Or if you don't it the dynamic way

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !192.168.1.1
```

Comment: i am just trying out the RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME},%{SERVER_ADDR} ^(.*),\1, so far it seems to be working, im assuming this compares %{SERVER_NAME} with %{SERVER_ADDR}

Comment: before posting i kind of assumed there would be a standard practice for achieving this

Comment: in fact it compares servername with something that matches everytime  .* :-) saves the result and compares it with serveraddr \1

Comment: i am new to serverfault. why did you mark my answer as unuseful? you said it worked out your problem accessing the ip addr...

Comment: hi i am also new to this :) i didnt, i was actually going to ask you the same thing but didnt want to bother you, i was also wondering why the question was marked down as well, i thought it was a useful question

Comment: i thought at the time it may have been only the first line of the answer, someone then marked it down and it was then edited, i decided to leave it open to try and get some more feedback

Comment: haha, ok, no worries. i found it useful :-) in fact i am new to Apache as well and bookmarked this question to remember a complete solution :-) for me it is useful as well, might not be for some Apache Guru :-)